# Pivottable (2 levels) NaN not showing

Tags: pandas, pivot-table

I have a dataframe, which I create from another dataframe:

```
df_exp_fix = df_aus[df_aus['CATEGORY'] == "Fixkosten"]
```

When I display df_exp_fix i get:

|  | MONTHYEAR | Comment | LEVEL2 | LEVEL3 | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 01.01.2022 | bla | Lebensmittel | Metro | 10 |
| 1 | 01.02.2022 | bla | Taschengeld | NaN | 10 |

Next I do

```
table_exp_fix = df_exp_fix.pivot_table(values='AMOUNT', index=['LEVEL2', 'LEVEL3'], 
                               columns=['MONTHYEAR'], aggfunc=np.sum, margins=True)
```

But the Line "Taschengeld" is not displayed?
And with that all Sums are not the same if I only aggregate on LEVEL2

I played around with dropna.... and other parameters but it doesn't get displayed

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is, because you have a `NaN` value in your index columns.

Try:

```
df_exp_fix['LEVEL3'].fillna('Unknown', inplace=True)
```

If you also have (possible) `NaN`'s in LEVEL2, replace these as well.

Also, to remove `NaN` values from your output, add `fill_value` parameter like this:

```
table_exp_fix = df.pivot_table(values='AMOUNT', index=['LEVEL2', 'LEVEL3'], 
                           columns=['MONTHYEAR'], aggfunc=np.sum, margins=True, fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
                MONTHYEAR   01.01.2022  01.02.2022  All
LEVEL2          LEVEL3          
Lebensmittel    Metro       10          0           10
Taschengeld     Unknown     0           10          10
All                         10          10          20
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - had to adjust my first line to: 
df_exp_fix = df_aus.loc[(df_aus['LEVEL1'] == "Fixkosten")].copy()

Comment: To help the community understand this answer successfully solved your problem, please also accept this answer as solution.